# How to automatically update number of products in angular cart without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, angular

I have made an angular cart ,in which I am saving products to local storage ,this is my AppService.ts

```
addtocart(userproduct:Product,quantity:number){
     //calling get products in local stored cart to fetch product
    const storedcart:Cart[]= this.getproducts();
    //checking if the incoming product is already there
    let item = storedcart.find(p => p.product.id == userproduct.id); 
    //if incoming product is not there
    if (item === undefined) {
        //creating a new cart element
        const newcart:Cart={product:userproduct,quantity:quantity};
        //pushing that product in already stored cart
        storedcart.push(newcart);
        //saving the cart again
        this.storage.set(this.key, storedcart);//saving cart to the local storage

    }
    //if the product existsthen just increaing the quantity of item
   else{
    item.quantity += quantity;
    //and saving the cart again to local browser storage
    this.storage.set(this.key, storedcart);//saving cart to the local storage
    console.log("Quantity of the product increased");

   }



  console.log(this.storage.get(this.key));

 }
```

this function is use in my product component

```
export class ProductsComponent   {
  products :Product[]=[
{id:"xy1",name:"SSR-3000-15-POS-TERMINAL",picture:"a.jpg",price:1375,category:"screentills"},
{id:"xy2",name:"SSR-T86E SCALE",picture:"b.jpg",price:1,category:"cashregister"},
{id:"xy3",name:"SSR-300-RECEIPT-PRINTERS",picture:"c.jpg",price:451,category:"printers"},
{id:"xy5",name:"EPSON-DOT-MATRIX-PRINTER",picture:"d.jpg",price:560,category:"kitchenprinter"},
{id:"xy6",name:"EPSON-DOT-MATRIX-PRINTER",picture:"d.jpg",price:560,category:"cashdrawers"},
{id:"xy7",name:"EPSON-DOT-MATRIX-PRINTER",picture:"d.jpg",price:560,category:"barcodescanner"},
{id:"xy8",name:"EPSON-DOT-MATRIX-PRINTER",picture:"d.jpg",price:560,category:"accessories"},


  ];
  //
  //dependency injection of appservice
  constructor(private appservice:AppService) { }

  addproduct(product){
    this.appservice.addtocart(product,1);

  }




}
```

Now to retrieve quantity of products ,I have this function from my appservice

```
gettotalproducts(){
    //getting stored cart from total products saved in local storage
    const storedcart:Cart[]= this.getproducts();

    //checking if products exist in cart then only returning size
     if(storedcart != null){
        this.cartsize=storedcart.length;
        return this.cartsize;
     }
     //else returning zero
    else{
        this.cartsize=0;
        return this.cartsize;
    }
```

in my header component which has a cart icon where i show total products

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  //totalproducts:number;
  constructor(private appservice:AppService) { }
  totalproducts= this.appservice.gettotalproducts();

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

this is the html snippet of header.component.html to display total

```
<li class="checkout">
                <a routerLink="/cart">
                  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <span id="checkout_items" class="checkout_items">{{totalproducts}}</span>
                </a>
              </li>
```

The product adds successfully to the cart and i get quantity too,but i have to

> refresh the page

everytime if i want to see the updated quantity in cart icon ,any idea how to do this without page refresh ,like when i add product to cart it automatically updates the cart icon number ,I tried this function in ngOninit but no success.I am fairly new to angular ,so any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Can you add the HTML template you're using to display the total please?

Comment: yeah i did please check

Comment: It looks like you're only setting` totalproducts` when the code is loaded into memory. Try changing your binding to `{{appservice.gettotalproducts()}}` and see if that helps

Comment: yeah it worked thanks :)